# Not able to interact with the chrome browser from selenium chrome driver without manual intervention

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a website that developed in Angular 6. When we try to launch the application using selenium with chrome driver, it loads the page but selenium not able to interact with the browser to find the element. If we do a double click on the page or outside of the browser anywhere on the screen, selenium starts the interaction and do the actions specified in the test case. This issue is identified only for chrome driver and all other browsers are working fine for the same site.

**Meta**

OS:
Windows 10

Selenium Version:
3.141

Driver version:
85.0.4183.87

Browser:
Chrome 85.0.4183.102

Comment: You need to specify the User-Agent in your request: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Then you need to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request in working browser with the c# request.  The add/change headers in c# to look like the browser request.